# #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add Foreign Key on table "menu" and getting Error as:

```
1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`#sql-c74_c5`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-c74_c5_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`restaurant_id`) REFERENCES `restaurants` (`restaurant_id`))
```

My Restaurant table has one of the columns `restaurant_id` and it is Primary Key for this table.

Menu table has three columns `menu_id`, `menu_name` and `restaurant_id`. Now when i run

```
ALTER TABLE `menu` ADD FOREIGN KEY ( `restaurant_id` ) REFERENCES `restaurants` (`restaurant_id`);
```

then i got error #1452.

Please help me out of it :)

Comment: THanks!! I have figured out the problem. 

Again index was not implemented on restaurant table.

M growing smarter :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the data already in that column does not meet the foreign key requirements, meaning, you either have a null value in restaurant_id in the "menu" table, or you have a value that does not exist in restaurant_id in restaurants.  If you want the foreign key to only be enforced from this point on, you need a "nocheck", otherwise you need to have the data meet the requirements of the constraint.  To add a nocheck foreign key, this is what you need:

```
ALTER TABLE menu with NOCHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_menu_restaurants] FOREIGN KEY ([restaurant_id])
REFERENCES restaurants([restaurant_id])
```

I hope this helps.